# Attaching files to nodes programmatically in Drupal 7 but File Name is blank?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to upload a file in drupal7, but the image name is blanc. If I use

```
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['app_icon']
```

then the uploaded file is .tmp formate. Is there any person who can guide me?

```
            $file_path  = drupal_realpath($_FILES['files']['name']['app_icon']);
            $file = (object) array(
                      'uid' => 1,
                      'uri' => $file_path,
                      'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
                      'status' => 1,                         
             );

            $file = file_copy($file, 'public://app-icons');             
            $node->field_application_icon[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
```

Comment: i have found many example , $file_path = drupal_realpath($_FILES['files']['name']['app_icon']); at all there is static path like $file_path = drupal_realpath("myimg.jpg"); how can we do it, during upload a new file? –

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the public folder whether this copy has been done there or not ? & a entry to the files table should go to show the attachment with your node..

Comment: if i used   
$file_path  = drupal_realpath($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['app_icon']);
then it will upload a tmp file, in public folder, if used 
$file_path  = drupal_realpath($_FILES['files']['name']['app_icon']);
then file path is blanck...

Comment: I didn't get your point. You are using file_copy for copying the file to destination. Get the current destination path from function file_directory_path(). Then make a path name like - $path = $dest.'/'.$filename; and then use file_copy to copy file to that location by file_copy($file, $dest) and insert $path to the DB where it's needed... This is what I know :)

Comment: $file = file_copy($file, 'public://app-icons'); 

first is source path, and 2nd is destination, source path is empty.
[field_application_icon] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: i have found many example , 
$file_path  = drupal_realpath($_FILES['files']['name']['app_icon']);
at all there is static path like
$file_path  = drupal_realpath("myimg.jpg");
how can we do it, during upload a new file?